# indirectly pushing std::array to heap with smart pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

`std::array`, unlike vector, stores its objects on the stack.  The code bellow is my attempt to push `std::array` and in particular (this is what is important)...push the items that `std::array` manages on to the heap.

```
class X{

private:
   array<Y,10> data;
}

auto upA = make_unique<X>();
```

Are the array elements of `std::array` in my example on the heap?  Is there a more elegant way to push `std::array` to heap?

Comment: what about `auto a = std::make_unique<std::array<Y, 10U>>()` ?

Comment: max66, nice.  Not sure these will go on heap, but it seems logical that temp std::array would be move compatible... but i'm not sure. vector is move compatible...but when vector is moved the objects it stores in the free store are not moved and need not support move semantics.  array may need the items it stores to also implement move semantics.

Comment: "not sure these will go on heap": you can check this with `sizeof()`: if `sizeof(std::array<Y, 10U>)` is far lower than `sizeof(std::array<Y, 100U>)`, you know that the important part of `std::array` (the `10` or `100` `Y` elements) are (using `new`) in the heap.

Comment: `std::make_unique<Anything>()` doesn't require `Anything` to be movable. It's not clear what your discussion of "move compatible" has to do with the issue at hand.

Comment: max66, not sure what you mean about sizeof.  an array of 10 elements is going to be less than an array of 100 elements.  if you take size of a ptr or smart ptr you get size of ptr.

Comment: Igor, what does temp exp std::array<Y, 10U>> return? Not a ptr, right?  There is no "new" in the temp expr.  It isn't clear to me how the allocation would be made and how and what kind of handle is given to unique_ptr..  When you add into vector... vector.push_back(Y("1"));  a temp ptr is not moved into vector...instead Y's move c'tor is triggered to create a copy of Y with pilfered resources from original Y.

Comment: `std::array<Y, 10U>>` is syntactically invalid and would fail to compile. `std::array<Y, 10U>` is the name of a type and not a valid expression. In light of these facts, I'm not sure I understand your question. `std::make_unique<std::array<Y, 10U>>()` is, in essence, just a nicer, more compact way to write `std::unique_ptr<std::array<Y, 10U>>(new std::array<Y, 10U>())`. That is, `make_unique` calls `new` inside - that's how the allocation is made. `vector.push_back(Y("1"))` doesn't appear to involve any pointers, temp or otherwise (unless you count `"1"` as a pointer to `const char`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, std::array doesn't store its objects on the stack, it stores them in-place that is wherever the std::array itself is stored. In other words: if you have an object with std::array as a member then this std::array will be stored wherever the object itself is stored. So if you allocate an object of your class X on the heap just by using operator new, then the array within this object will also be on the heap along with the object.

On the other hand you don't really need to create a class and an object for this you can just do:

```
auto a = new std::array<Y, 10>;
```

Comment: correct; but, starting from C++11 I ever try to discourage the direct management of allocated memory and to suggest the use of smart pointers.

Comment: Sure, but the point of the question is to figure out which type of memory is used, and not the dynamic memory management, so adding smart pointers to the mix might confuse the issue further.